# How to measure client's rating?

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics

I am currently developing a mail system where a client can send bulk messages to email addresses. For this kind of system there is an important limitation - the client must not send messages that may appear in spam, because in this case the reputation of the platform is endangered.

After my client sends messages, I receive notifications from the recipient’s service providers (gmail, outlook) whether this message was thrown into spam. Thus, my client can send 1000 messages to a thousand recipients and I can track what percentage of these letters were thrown into spam. Therefore, I must reduce the reputation of the client until he improves the quality of his messages. If a client with low account rating continuously sends messages with good result, then the account rating will be reestablished. Here is the data I have:

- the number of emails sent within a certain day.
- the number of emails thrown to spam during a certain day.

**For example:** the client has the following history

> 01.12.19 client has sent 1000 emails 5 of which appeared in spam (0.5% spam)
>
> 02.12.19 client has sent 2000 emails 10 of which appeared in spam (0.5% spam)
>
> 03.12.19 client has sent 500 emails 10 of which appeared in spam (2% spam)
>
> 04.12.19 client has sent 5000 emails 42 of which appeared in spam (0.8% spam)
>
> 05.12.19 client has sent 18125 emails 654 of which appeared in spam (3.6% spam)
>
> 07.12.19 client has sent 50000 emails 1000 of which appeared in spam (2% spam)
>
> 08.12.19 client has sent 45682 emails 134 of which appeared in spam (0.3% spam)
>
> 09.12.19 client has sent 100000 emails 20000 of which appeared in spam (20% spam).

I set a limit of 5%. When the client sends emails and more than 5% of these emails appear in spam, the account rating is reduced. As you can see on 09.12.19, the client had 20% spam, so the account rating will be lowered. 20% of spam is a troublesome indicator - apparently my client sends low-quality letters.

Everything was fine and the system worked properly until I met cunning clients who learned how to quickly restore their account. After their account rating is lowered, my client sends 2 letters every day, both letters do not appear in the spam. As a result, my client sends several emails every day - 100% of which are successful (0% spam). I realized that I have a problem calculating the rating. I want to get a formula for calculating customer ratings. To solve this problem, I realized that it was necessary to use the history of sent letters and take an average rating so that the client cannot deceive me. That is, if earlier the client sent 50,000 messages, then several complete messages within a few days cannot correct the situation and change their rating.

Here we approach the problem itself. My product specification team has set a task for me, and that is- the earlier history of the account should not influence current actions on the account. It is possible that my client sent for 50,000 letters every day (1,500 of which are spam - which is in the limit), but then he started sending 50 letters every day (2 of those spam - which are normal). If I consider the average of the entire history, the client will have a reduced rating for a long time. I think the latest data should be more significant than the earlier data. We can apply for example, the logarithmic decay to the client’s date, which means the numbers that come first are more significant that the ones after. I understand that the task is quite complicated that’s why I’ll bring examples of how my system should work.

**Example 1.** All account indicators are within the norm - the rating is good

> 01.12.19 client has sent 100 emails 2 of which appeared in spam (2% spam)
>
> 02.12.19 client has sent 256 emails 4 of which appeared in spam (1.6% spam)
>
> 03.12.19 client has sent 486 emails 7 of which appeared in spam (1.4% spam)
>
> 04.12.19 client has sent 4678 emails 80 of which appeared in spam (1.7% spam)
>
> 05.12.19 client has sent 684 emails 13 of which appeared in spam (1.9% spam)
>
> 07.12.19 client has sent 50000 emails 1000 of which appeared in spam (2% spam)

**Example 2.** All account indicators are within the norm - the rating is good. During the last days 50% of emails appeared in spam. However, this is just one email message, which is technically allowed, and the account should not be blocked because of this.

> 01.12.19 client has sent 1000 emails 5 of which appeared in spam (0.5% spam)
>
> 02.12.19 client has sent 2000 emails 10 of which appeared in spam (0.5% spam)
>
> 03.12.19 client has sent 500 emails 10 of which appeared in spam (2% spam)
>
> 04.12.19 client has sent 5000 emails 42 of which appeared in spam (0.8% spam)
>
> 05.12.19 client has sent 45682 emails 134 of which appeared in spam (0.3% spam)
>
> 06.12.19 client has sent 2 emails 1 of which appeared in spam (50% spam)
>
> 07.12.19 client has sent 2 emails 1 of which appeared in spam (50% spam)
>
> 08.12.19 client has sent 2 emails 1 of which appeared in spam (50% spam)

**Example 3.** All account indicators are within the norm - the rating is good. Million emails were sent on the first day, but the spam percentage is within the norm.

> 01.12.19 client has sent 1000000 emails 20000 of which appeared in spam (2% spam)

**Example 4.** Account rating should be reduced because it sent too much spam.

> 01.12.19 client has sent 1000 emails 5 of which appeared in spam (0.5% spam)
>
> 02.12.19 client has sent 2000 emails 10 of which appeared in spam (0.5% spam)
>
> 03.12.19 client has sent 500 emails 10 of which appeared in spam (2% spam)
>
> 04.12.19 client has sent 5000 emails 42 of which appeared in spam (0.8% spam)
>
> 05.12.19 client has sent 18125 emails 654 of which appeared in spam (3.6% spam)
>
> 07.12.19 client has sent 50000 emails 1000 of which appeared in spam (2% spam)
>
> 08.12.19 client has sent 45682 emails 134 of which appeared in spam (0.3% spam)
>
> 09.12.19 client has sent 100000 emails 20000 of which appeared in spam (20% spam)

**Example 5.** The account rating has been reduced (08.12.19), then the account sent out emails with positive result, however the account rating should not be improved, since several successful emails cannot fix the situation.

> 01.12.19 client has sent 1000 emails 5 of which appeared in spam (0.5% spam)
>
> 02.12.19 client has sent 2000 emails 10 of which appeared in spam (0.5% spam)
>
> 03.12.19 client has sent 500 emails 10 of which appeared in spam (2% spam)
>
> 04.12.19 client has sent 5000 emails 42 of which appeared in spam (0.8% spam)
>
> 05.12.19 client has sent 18125 emails 654 of which appeared in spam (3.6% spam)
>
> 06.12.19 client has sent 50000 emails 3548 of which appeared in spam (7.1% spam)
>
> 07.12.19 client has sent 45682 emails 134 of which appeared in spam (0.3% spam)
>
> 08.12.19 client has sent 100000 emails 20000 of which appeared in spam (20% spam)
>
> 09.12.19 client has sent 1 email 0 of which appeared in spam (0% spam)
>
> 10.12.19 client has sent 1 email 0 of which appeared in spam (0% spam)
>
> 11.12.19 client has sent 1 email 0 of which appeared in spam (0% spam)
>
> 12.12.19 client has sent 1 email 0 of which appeared in spam (0% spam)
>
> 13.12.19 client has sent 1 email 0 of which appeared in spam (0% spam)
>
> 14.12.19 client has sent 1 email 0 of which appeared in spam (0% spam)
>
> 15.12.19 client has sent 1 email 0 of which appeared in spam (0% spam)

**Example 6.** Although the account has reduced rating (04.12.19), the results have been positive lately, consequently, the account rating should be improved.

> 01.12.19 client has sent 100 emails 2 of which appeared in spam (2% spam)
>
> 02.12.19 client has sent 256 emails 4 of which appeared in spam (1.6% spam)
>
> 03.12.19 client has sent 486 emails 7 of which appeared in spam (1.4% spam)
>
> 04.12.19 client has sent 10000 emails 2000 of which appeared in spam (20% spam)
>
> 05.12.19 client has sent 4678 emails 80 of which appeared in spam (1.7% spam)
>
> 06.12.19 client has sent 684 emails 13 of which appeared in spam (1.9% spam)
>
> 07.12.19 client has sent 500 emails 10 of which appeared in spam (2% spam)

So, I have the following 2 questions: is it possible to solve this problem with one formula? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a threshold, which makes that only a larger amount of letters has any influence at all.

A very simple python implementation:

```
def f(reputation, letters, spam):
    x = 1
    if spam/letters > 0.05:
        x = -1
    if letters > 1000: # only if more than 1000 letters are send
        reputation += x*(100*spam/letters) # the 100 is arbitrary: change it according to your needs
        if reputation < 0:
            reputation = 0
        if reputation > 100:
            reputation = 100
    return reputation







EXAMPLE  0
letters: 100 spam: 2 (2.0%)
current reputation:  100
_____
letters: 256 spam: 4 (1.5625%)
current reputation:  100
_____
letters: 50000 spam: 1000 (2.0%)
current reputation:  100


EXAMPLE  1
letters: 1000 spam: 5 (0.5%)
current reputation:  100
_____
letters: 2000 spam: 10 (0.5%)
current reputation:  100
_____
letters: 2 spam: 1 (50.0%)
current reputation:  100
_____
letters: 2 spam: 1 (50.0%)
current reputation:  100
_____
letters: 3 spam: 2 (66.66666666666667%)
current reputation:  100


EXAMPLE  2
letters: 1000000 spam: 20000 (2.0%)
current reputation:  100


EXAMPLE  3
letters: 100 spam: 2 (2.0%)
current reputation:  100
_____
letters: 256 spam: 4 (1.5625%)
current reputation:  100
_____
letters: 100000 spam: 20000 (20.0%)
current reputation:  80.0


EXAMPLE  4
letters: 100 spam: 5 (5.0%)
current reputation:  100
_____
letters: 2000 spam: 100 (5.0%)
current reputation:  100
_____
letters: 500 spam: 10 (2.0%)
current reputation:  100
_____
letters: 100000 spam: 20000 (20.0%)
current reputation:  80.0
_____
letters: 1 spam: 0 (0.0%)
current reputation:  80.0
_____
letters: 1 spam: 0 (0.0%)
current reputation:  80.0
_____
letters: 1 spam: 0 (0.0%)
current reputation:  80.0
```

If you need a like a smooth transition instead of a threshold I would use the sigmoid function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)